# Calculate days between dates in LiveCycle Designer

Tags: javascript, livecycle

I have seen and read a number of comments regarding calculating the days between dates, as it relates to JS. My question is-I need to calculate this information in Adobe LiveCycle Designer. I have the two fields I need to reference in the script. The first is the static field with the last known date of an event, the second is the current date/time (which is entered by the end user). I need to know how to write the script to find the difference between these two fields, with the calculation resulting in days. I do not need to be exact, daylight savings time, leap year, time zones etc. are not important. Just need to get to an integer. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty way to do it involves an epoch subtraction. In Javascript, the date epoch is available from `Date.getTime();` as seen on [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp). If you're looking for a more robust approach and if you have a need for additional date and time operation, I would suggest looking into [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/). Moment.js is technically a JavaScript library aimed at browsers, etc. but it can be [wrapped in a Script Object to be used in an XFA form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26587484/including-moment-js-in-livecycle-designer).